# Combining 2 servos and sensor over 1 serial

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

I am trying to connect over same serial 2 servos and distance sensor. In Arduino, I have this code. If I write in Arduino's serial monitor values for my servos like 120,120, it works. I wrote a program in python to change values depending on the result of the sensor, but the program sends values, but nothing is happening. Can you help me what I am doing wrong?

```
#include <NewPing.h>
#include <Servo.h>
#define TRIGGER_PIN   12  // Arduino pin tied to trigger pin on the ultrasonic sensor.
#define ECHO_PIN      11 // Arduino pin tied to echo pin on the ultrasonic sensor.
#define MAX_DISTANCE  200 // Maximum distance we want to ping for (in centimeters). Maximum sensor distance is rated at 400-500cm.

NewPing sonar(TRIGGER_PIN, ECHO_PIN, MAX_DISTANCE); // NewPing setup of pins and maximum distance.

Servo servo1;  
Servo servo2; 
int num1,num2;  

void setup()
{
  servo1.attach(9);
  servo2.attach(10);
  Serial.begin(115200); // Open serial at 115200 baud to see ping results.
}

void loop()
{
   Serial.println(sonar.ping_cm(),DEC); 
   num1= Serial.parseInt(); 
   num2= Serial.parseInt();          
   servo1.write(num1);     
   servo2.write(num2); 
}
```

**Program in python**

```
if  mean10 > 8:
             ser.write( "130,130".encode())                
else:
             ser.write( "30,30".encode())
```

Comment: Why are you using the `encode()` function? Also, I think the serial is sending strings because they're enclosed in double inverted commas.

Comment: I deleted .encode().  So my function looks like this 
if  mean10 > 8:  
             ser.write( (130,130))            
        else:
             ser.write( (30,30))

This didnt change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I tried and it worked out. Hopefully, it'll work for you out too.

Arduino code:

```
Serial.println(sonar.ping_cm(),DEC); 
num = Serial.parseInt();
num1= num / 1000;
num2= num % 1000;         
servo1.write(num1);     
servo2.write(num2);
```

Python Code:

```
if  mean10 > 8:
    data = "130" + "130"
    ser.write(data.encode())                
else:
    data = "030" + "030"
    ser.write(data.encode())
```

Alternatively:

Arduino Side:

```
Serial.println(sonar.ping_cm(),DEC); 
num = Serial.parseInt();
if(num == 1){
    num1 = 30;
    num2 = 30;
}
else if(num == 2){
    num1 = 130;
    num2 = 130;
}
servo1.write(num1);     
servo2.write(num2);
```

Python Code:

```
if  mean10 > 8:
    data = 1
    ser.write(data)                
else:
    data = 2
    ser.write(data)
```

Comment: I changed my code, but it still not works. I checked my servos are well connected. In your  method i had error "communicating…unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes" . So i changed data to b'130'+'130'.  Still no effect.

Comment: I've used the method in python 2.7 and it works flawlessly. Mind trying that?

Comment: Sorry, that's not an option,  this is a part of my project in which I used some libs from python3.

Comment: I understand. I'll try something for python 3 then

Comment: I've made the necessary changes and now this method works for me in python 3.6 and pySerial 3.4

Comment: I am grateful for help, but still this isn't working.

Comment: Problem is, there is none error.  I see on my graph data from sensor,  030030 
 or 130130 is printed in a console,  but servos don't move.

Comment: Try to print num1 and num2 in the Serial monitor and see if they're equal to 130,130 and 30,30

Comment: Also is the "030030" being printed on the sender's end or receiver's end?

Comment: So, it works now? Is everything cool? And what was the error?

Comment: Well, it only works for else value now, but servos don't change to 130 and I don't know why. I keep trying on my own, i don't want to trouble you so much :)

Comment: You don't trouble me don't worry :). Can you please share full codes so that I can get a better understanding?

Comment: I've added an alternate method. I think this should work

Comment: Thank you.  I just modify to this, and it works. You wrote it for python 2 I think.   But now it is working properly. 
if:
     data = "1"
    
             ser.write((data.encode()) )     
        else:
             data = "2" 
             ser.write((data.encode()) )

Comment: No, it worked for python 3 too. I created data as an integer and not as a string so I didn't need to include `encode()`. It works both ways. Happy to help :)